# Convert a Lazy ByteString to a strict ByteString

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, strict, bytestring, chunking

I have a function that takes a [lazy `ByteString`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/latest/doc/html/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html#v:all), that I wish to have return lists of [strict `ByteStrings`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/latest/doc/html/Data-ByteString.html#v:all) (the laziness should be transferred to the list type of the output).

```
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L
csVals :: L.ByteString -> [B.ByteString]
```

I want to do this for various reasons, [several lexing functions](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring-lexing/0.1.2/doc/html/Data-ByteString-Lex-Double.html) require strict `ByteString`s, and I can guarantee the outputted strict `ByteString`s in the output of `csVal`s above are very small.

**How do I go about "strictifying" `ByteString`s without [chunking](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/latest/doc/html/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html#v:toChunks) them?**

### Update0

I want to take a Lazy `ByteString`, and make one strict `ByteString` containing all its data.

Comment: What is your problem with [`toChunks`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/latest/doc/html/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html#v%3atoChunks)? From the initial glimpse it looks like it preserves laziness.

Comment: @Matt Joiner:Maybe you should write a lexing yourself, or force eval the results using DeepSeq.

Comment: @Matt Joiner: there is a Lazy version: 'Data.ByteString.Lex.Lazy.Double' in the same package.

Comment: @Matt Joiner: so you want chunks of specified size? Possibly repeated calls to splitAt?  Note that toChunks generates strict ByteStrings are of maximum size (except for possibly the last one).

Comment: @MikhailGlushenkov: toChunks returns a list of strict ByteStrings. I want them all in one.

Comment: @WuXingbo: I have switched to the Lazy readDouble for now, thanks. My question still stands however.

Comment: There's a misunderstanding here -- a lazy bytestring *is* just a list of chunks (i.e. strict bytestrings), essentially. `toChunks` exposes that structure. To put the list all in one strict bytestring, there's no other way than `concat . toChunks` (or the equiv). In many typical cases, the list will have a single element -- in those cases `concat . toChunks` will be relatively efficient as well.

Comment: @sclv: What you describe is what I'm after.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Like @sclv said in the comments above, a lazy bytestring is just a list of strict bytestrings. There are two approaches to converting lazy ByteString to strict (source: [haskell mailing list discussion about adding toStrict function](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.libraries/16444)) - relevant code from the email thread below:

First, relevant libraries:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString               as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Internal      as BI
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy          as BL
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal as BLI
import           Foreign.ForeignPtr
import           Foreign.Ptr
```

Approach 1 (same as @sclv):

```
toStrict1 :: BL.ByteString -> B.ByteString
toStrict1 = B.concat . BL.toChunks
```

Approach 2:

```
toStrict2 :: BL.ByteString -> B.ByteString
toStrict2 BLI.Empty = B.empty
toStrict2 (BLI.Chunk c BLI.Empty) = c
toStrict2 lb = BI.unsafeCreate len $ go lb
  where
    len = BLI.foldlChunks (\l sb -> l + B.length sb) 0 lb

    go  BLI.Empty                   _   = return ()
    go (BLI.Chunk (BI.PS fp s l) r) ptr =
        withForeignPtr fp $ \p -> do
            BI.memcpy ptr (p `plusPtr` s) (fromIntegral l)
            go r (ptr `plusPtr` l)
```

If performance is a concern, I recommend checking out the email thread above. It has criterion benchmark as well. toStrict2 is faster than toStrict1 in those benchmarks.

Answer (score 39):

The `bytestring` package now exports a `toStrict` function:

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/0.10.2.0/doc/html/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html#v:toStrict

This might not be exactly what you want, but it certainly answers the question in the title of this post :)

Comment: any clue in which version this was added though? It seems it's not there in the Haskell platform 2012.4 (including ghc 7.4)?

Answer (score 5):

If the lazy ByteString in question is <= the maximum size of a strict ByteString:

```
toStrict = fromMaybe SB.empty . listToMaybe . toChunks
```

`toChunks` makes each chunk be as large as possible (except for possibly the last one).

If the size of you lazy ByteString is *larger* than what a strict ByteString can be, then this isn't possible: that's exactly what lazy ByteStrings are for.

Answer (score 2):

Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 now has toStrict and fromStrict functions.

Comment: This appears to be essentially a duplicate of ocharles's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [blaze-builder](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/blaze-builder-0.3.1.1) to build strict ByteString from lazy

```
toStrict :: BL.ByteString -> BS.ByteString
toStrict = toByteString . fromLazyByteString
```

It must be effective.